# linux - command line to get version of terminal

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I use a terminal which I don't know the name. By which command can I find the name and version of that?

(I use android operating system)

Comment: Don't understand your question. Or are you looking for the  `uname` command? This should be on superuser or U&L questions anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

echo $TERM tells you kind of terminal you are using, eg. xterm